# Is there a way to have an IF statement look for even or odd numbers?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am very new to coding and am trying to make a camera check out/check-in system using a google form and google sheet. I am using a bar code scanner to scan in the camera on the google form which is linked then to the google sheet. Right now I am trying to get the sheet to count how many times the bar code was scanned in and then based on that tell me if the camera is checked in or out. So if the bar code is scanned in only once I now someone checked it out but if it is scanned twice I know it has been returned and then when it appears a third time it is checked out again and so on and so forth.

I have already tried using `LOOKUP` but it only searches one row and I want to be able to check in several items at once. I also tried using `VLOOKUP` but it doesn't work either.

This is the code that I have so far but it only works once since it only looks if a code has been scanned in once or several times

```
=If(COUNTIF(Data_Entered!$E$2:$I$6,A2) = 0, "Check In", "Check Out")
```

I want it that instead of only saying = 0 that I can say = even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISODD(COUNTIF(A2:A, "<>")), "online", "ofline")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(ISODD(IF(A2:A<>"", ROW(A1:A), )), "on", "off"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I want the name of the person who checked out the item to be written next to where it says check in or check out. The data I get from the google form gives me the name of the person who checks out the item. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @ThaddeusSieverding https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi3Ix.png - `=QUERY(C2:C, "offset "&COUNTA(C2:C)-1, 0)`

Comment: I tried implementing the code into my google sheet but I do not understand it. Could you explain what you are doing with the code?

Comment: @ThaddeusSieverding sure, we input range C2:C in QERY and then offset rows to get last entry. so if there are 9 rows in C2:C we offset it by 8 rows to get 9th row. COUNTA will count all non-empty rows and give us 9. then 9-1 = 8. the last parameter 0 in query is to make sure query won't misinterpret some rows as header rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use MOD.  Ex.) =MOD(A1,2)
It will return a 1 if odd, 0 if even.